# What determines if an achievement is a rare achievement?

Tags: achievements, xbox-one

I've noticed that after a recent update to my Xbox One, some achievements are considered "rare."  A diamond will appear in the notification for the achievement when it is unlocked.  Some of these achievements I've seen the diamond on are rather easy, and I don't get how they are considered "rare."

What determines or at what point is an achievement considered rare?

Comment: If it's like Playstation it would be determined by the % of people who got it. an easy to get story progression trophies in a PS3, PS4 or PSVita game can be "rare" if people dropped the game and didn't play it through (ie. some Sword Art Online Hollow Fragment Trophies for clearing floors/Hollow Area Bosses or Persona 4 Golden Trophies for saving main characters)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the patch notes video for this update it was stated that an achievement is Rare if less than 10% of all players (who have started that game) have gotten it. This means an achievement can be rare, and then as more people get it, it becomes a regular achievement.

I can't find an official MS post, but [this post](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.trueachievements.com/n25413/xbox-achievement-rarity-now-integrated-into-trueachievements.htm) on trueachievements.com confirms that 10% calculation.

Comment: So in essence, it is rare simply because people didn't get it, and as more people chase these rare achievements, it gets... less rare.  This is actually really funny.  Probably drives OCD people insane.

Comment: So, basically does it mean that after some time there will be no rare achievements?

Comment: No, because there will always be achievements that not all players can get, and people will just simply stop playing the game.